# How to read XML file in workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I want create workflow for my document lib and this workflow i want to read the XML files and update this value to my other list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use SharePoint designer to achieve your goal . in this case, you will need to develop an Event Receiver on item added via C# SSOM or use a Powershell script .

**Event Receiver Steps**

- Create an event receiver check [Creating Simple Event Receiver in SharePoint 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/5b1f04/creating-simple-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2013/)
- Read an XML file via C# and set it to data table for more details check [How To Read XML Data into a DataSet by Using C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311566)
- Loop in this data table and add this data to list as the following

**Code :**

```
void BinddatatabletoList()
     {
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         dt= GetDatafromSQL();

     using (SPSite oSite=new SPSite("http://mysharepoint"))
      {

       using (SPWeb oWeb=oSite.RootWeb)
        {
            SPList oList = oWeb.Lists["Test"];
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
            {
            SPListItem oSPListItem = oList.Items.Add();
            oSPListItem["Title"] = row["Title"].ToString();
            oSPListItem.Update();
            }
        }
     }
     }
```

**Alternative solution via PowerShell**

You can use the following PowerShell script to read from XML and import to SharePoint list , Then build a windows task schedule to run this script as mentioned at [Running a SharePoint PowerShell script from Task Scheduler](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/01/running-sharepoint-powershell-script.html)

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Set these two variables accordingly
$WebURL  = "http://project.crescent.com/"
$ListName = "External Projects"
$XMLFilePath = "D:\data\ExternalProjects.xml"

#Get the Web
$web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
#Get the List
$ProjectList = $web.Lists[$ListName]

#import xml file
[xml]$ProjectXmlFile = Get-Content $XMLFilePath

foreach ($XMLProject in $ProjectXmlFile.projects.project)
 {
        $NewProject = $ProjectList.Items.Add()

        $NewProject["Project ID"] = $XMLProject.id
        $NewProject["Description"] = $XMLProject.description
        #Set the People Picker Field
        $NewProject["Project Manager"] = $web.EnsureUser($XMLProject.manager)
        $NewProject["Cost"] = $XMLProject.cost
        $NewProject["Start Date"] = $XMLProject.startdate

        $NewProject.Update()

        Write-Host "Project $($XMLProject.id) has been Added to External Projects list!"
 }
```

Read more: [read from XML and import to SharePoint list](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/02/import-xml-data-into-sharepoint-list.html#ixzz4PhhYuR7O)